# How to merge tables in longtable?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, longtable

From the last example in this link as below

[example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0G0b.png)

However, I have two question since for the long table, some part of it separates in two-part like this figure! How can I move some text from the second page to the first page?

And how can I put the number "1" into the center of the square?

Any suggestion on how to do that?  What's the best way to achieve that?

Please see my code and table!

Any suggestion on how to do that?

[image]

```
    \rowcolor{gray!30}
\textbf{3} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{Chapter 2: THEORY (to be continued)}}\\
     \hline
  & 
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.2cm]
    \vspace{-0.5cm}
    \itemsep-0.4em 
         \item Resources for normal size screens. (This is the baseline size.); 
         \item Resources for normal size screens. (This is the baseline size.)
         \item Resources for normal size screens. (This is the baseline size.)
         \item Resources for normal size screens. (This is the baseline size.)
         \item Resources for normal size screens. (This is the baseline size.)
  \vspace{-0.5cm}       
  \end{itemize}
  &    
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.2cm]
  \vspace{-0.5cm}
  \itemsep-0.4em
       \item Resources for normal size screens. (This is the baseline size.)
  \vspace{-0.5cm}
  \end{itemize}      
  &   
  1
\\
\hline
```

Comment: a pagebreak is only possible _after_  a tabular row, but not inside it. You have to split the `itemize` environment in two parts (tabular rows). Then a page break can be done between these two rows.

Comment: @Herbert do you know how can I move "1" to the center of the box? Thanks

Comment: only the cell with "1" or the complete column? And verti9cal or horizontally centered? or both?

Comment: I mean a center of square is a regular quadrilateral, which means that it has four equal sides and four equal angles (90-degree angles, or (100-gradian angles or right angles). I want to put "1" at the center of square as explained above! Is it both vertical and horizontally?

Thanks a lot